# disadvantage of CRUD pattern

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, crud

does anyone ever use the CRUD pattern?
whether the correct that implementation of crud pattern consume more memory because of generalised format they are written, to store any kind of data?
Thank's for all..

Answer (score 1):

CRUD is not a pattern of any sort. It simply stands for Create, Read, Update, Delete in reference to those 4 particular actions one might want to perform on any data.

[Wikipedia on CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)

[Wikipedia on Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Pattern)

Comment: in the book of Java Enterprise Design Pattern by Mark Grand. CRUD pattern is one part of a database pattern. he defines it as CRUD Pattern in interface class..    how about that?

Comment: Oh goodness. Personally I would not consider Java EE design patterns to be actual design patterns to the rest of the planet. But I don't want to start a religious war here. If you want to learn about real, world-accepted design patterns, check out the GOF's book on the subject. http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612

Comment: Mark, the GOF talk about pattern discovery.  They discuss how one notices that a particular approach is discovered to be used again and again, across projects.  Sometimes it's rediscovered, independently discovered, etc.  When you want to describe such a solution, the GOF have built a framework, and described item is called it a "Software Pattern".  CRUD objects might not be the choice solution for many cases, and it might not even be the best solution for the problems it is applied to, but it is certainly a software pattern.